# Running Kudu in a docker and master to tserver two-way connection / circular link issues - docker composition

Tags: docker, docker-compose, apache-kudu

How can you run Kudu, which requires two containers - one for the master and one for the tserver under docker, when the two containers need to connect to each other by DNS.

Kudu can be run under Docker using the following commands:

```
docker run --name kudu-master --hostname kudu-master --detach --publish 8051:8051 --publish 7051:7051 kunickiaj/kudu master
```

and:

```
docker run --name kudu-tserver --hostname kudu-tserver --detach --publish 8050:8050 --publish 7050:7050 --link kudu-master --env KUDU_MASTER=kudu-master kunickiaj/kudu tserver
```

However, the above defines a one way link, from `kudu-tserver` to `kudu-master` and not vice verse.

For Kudu to function correctly, bother `kudu-master` and `kudu-tserver` need to be able to connect to each other.

How can the Docker containers be configured, so that the two way link works?

- [Docker image reference](https://hub.docker.com/r/kunickiaj/kudu/)
- [Similar image reference](https://hub.docker.com/r/nemccarthy/docker-kudu/)

Answer (score 1):

The link parameter in docker run is a legacy feature which may be removed (references [[1]](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#network-settings) and [[2]](https://docs.docker.com/network/links/)).

You can raise multiple Docker containers and connect them to each other using `docker-compose`.

To get this working, create a folder named `kudu` and place the following `docker-compose.yml` file under it:

```
version: '3'
services:
  kudu-master:
    image: "kunickiaj/kudu"
    hostname: kudu-master
    ports:
      - "8051:8051"
      - "7051:7051"
    command:
      master
    networks:
      kudu_network:
        aliases:
          - kudu-master
  kudu-tserver:
    image: "kunickiaj/kudu"
    hostname: kudu-tserver
    ports:
      - "8050:8050"
      - "7050:7050"
    environment:
      - KUDU_MASTER=kudu-master
    command:
      tserver
    networks:
      kudu_network:
        aliases:
          - kudu-tserver
networks:
  kudu_network:
```

This file includes 2 services (`kudu-master` and `kudu-tserver`) and a network within which both have aliases which are visible to the rest of the network (to each other). [[File reference]](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

Then run `docker-compose` using the following command line:

```
docker-compose -f "filePathToYourDockerComposeYmlFile" up -d
```

or, if you want to recreate the Docker containers:

```
docker-compose -f "filePathToYourDockerComposeYmlFile" up -d --force-recreate
```

Other useful commands [[reference]](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/):

To stop the containers:

```
docker-compose -f "filePathToYourDockerComposeYmlFile" stop
```

To remove the containers:

```
docker-compose -f "filePathToYourDockerComposeYmlFile" rm -f
```